# button disabled - how to alter appearance

Tags: javascript, css, html, dart

How can I change the appearance of an html button when it is disabled and back when enabled? I want the button to remain visible, and I don't want to alter the text of the button. I want to alter it from code.

Comment: With [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:disabled).  I'm not really sure what your problem is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[For example](http://jsfiddle.net/tet3m/):

```
button {
  border: 3px solid #009;
  background: #66c;
  color: #fff;
}
button:disabled {
  border: 3px solid #66c;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Note, as per the [link in my comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3adisabled), the `:disabled` pseudo class is not supported in IE8 and earlier.

Comment: IE button elements have a pretty good default disabled state, with no extra styling. button:disabled css will cover most of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

CSS offers :disabled Selector.

[More information on CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp)

---

If you do not want to use CSS3 selectors, you may create new class and design it in a way you want.

But after that you will have to add flag "disabled" and use `return false;` if flag is set.

Comment: I don't have a problem altering the disabled attribute from true to false and back. The problem that I have is that the appearance of the button does not alter. I want the appearance to show that it is enabled or disabled in a similar way that an <input type="text"> field changes when disabled.